# How to make more than 40 security() calls?

Tags: pine-script

I know the maximum number of security() calls in pinescript is 40 but I came across following workaround from [pinecoder.com](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/) :

> The limit for security() calls is 40, but by using functions returning tuples with security(), you can fetch many more values than 40.

I don't exactly get what the workaround is! I would appreciate if someone can describe it with and example for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fetching 7 datapoints with one `security()` call, by using [tuples](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#tuples).

```
//@version=4
study("Test", "Test", true)

// Fetching 7 datapoints with one security() call.
[o,h,l,c,h2,h3,h4] = security(syminfo.ticker, timeframe.period, [open,high,low,close,hl2,hlc3,ohlc4])

plot( o, "open",  color.red)
plot( h, "high",  color.green)
plot( l, "low",   color.blue)
plot( c, "close", color.fuchsia)
plot(h2, "hl2",   color.lime)
plot(h3, "hlc3",  color.maroon)
plot(h4, "ohlc4", color.orange)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was under the impression that this way we can retrieve more than 40 instruments' prices! Sp is there a way to overcome that limitation?

Comment: You can't use more than 40 `security()` calls. This is clearly stated in your question, and that's a hard limit in Pine. The workaround is not to have more `security()` calls, but to be able to fetch many more values than 40, with those 40 `security()` calls, by using `tuples`. As demonstrated in my answer, 7 values are fetched with one `security()` call. So by using the maximum 40 `security()` calls, you could fetch `7 x 40 = 280` values.

Comment: Bjorn Mistiaen in my script I just call security for 4 times & it gives me an error "Script requests too many securities: 88. The limit is 40"