# PineScript, two indicator function but only one security call

Tags: pine-script

suppose i have two indicator functions in Pinescript, e.g. like below:

f_T1()=>
whatever logic here......
[a, b]

f_T2()=>
another set of logic here......
[d,e,f]

if i want to reference different timeframe and security to form a dashboard....
i do a security call like below:
[_a,_b] =  security(_ticker, timeframe.period, f_T1())
[_d,_e,_f] =  security(_ticker, timeframe.period, f_T2())

this works....but is there a way i can call T1() and T2() in ONE SINGLE security call?
the reason is TradingView limit the total number of security calling to 40.
if i calculate different indicators (like T1 and T2 in the above cases), doing it the above way will be wasting the security calls as its basically referencing to the same timeframe data.
Is here a way to get around it?

Thanks a lot and much appreicate!

Comment: I haven’t tested it my myself, but you can check tuples as demonstrated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621780/how-to-make-more-than-40-security-calls)

Answer (score 0):

Either use one function for all your calculations, or create another function that returns all the variables you need.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_get_open_close() => [open, close]
f_get_high_low() => [high, low]

f_get_em_all() =>
    [o, c] = f_get_open_close()
    [h, l] = f_get_high_low()
    [o, c, h, l]

[_o, _c, _h, _l] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f_get_em_all())

plot(_c)
```